# Browsermob proxy how to make it work with selenium grid? [java]

Tags: grid, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

What I have in my code:

```
public BrowserMobProxy getProxy() throws UnknownHostException {
    if (proxy == null) {
        proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        proxy.start(0);
    }
    return proxy;

seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(getProxy());
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
```

The problem is running on local its fine but running it on grid(either own  or browserstack) it is not working. Is there any way how to make it work - proxy running on local and listening to remote driver?

I tried:

```
proxy.start(0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
```

But without success.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem by using standalone browsermob instance and connecting to it via REST api. You can manage remote instance using simple GET/POST/PUT requests as described in REST API section: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy

**OR** you could try and expose your local proxy(but it will be necessary to assigned real address to it) externally and see what is going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with the same issue.
I use the following stack:

- BrowserMobProxy (https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)
- Selenoid (https://github.com/aandryashin/selenoid) -> this tool is a Selenium Hub in Docker, for remote driver it works absolutely the same as usual Se Grid.

I get it working by the following code (I make bold the key code):

```
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);
    Proxy seleniumProxy = null;    
seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    String ipAddress = new NetworkUtils().getIp4NonLoopbackAddressOfThisMachine().getHostAddress();
    int port = proxy.getPort();
    seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(ipAddress + ":" + port);
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
                    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("your_selnium_hub_ip:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

Comment: Does not work for me, adding the proxy results in the browser displaying `No internet` page

Comment: This solution rarely works in CI environments, as the localhost executing BMP (usually GitLab, Bamboo agent etc.)  must be accessible from remote browser (typically cloud-deployed).